# How to use os environment variable in main class, which set through multiprocessing sub methods? multiprocessing scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am working on application where multiprocessing is used.

```
# Main class
# some code...

def executor():
  os.environ['test_count'] = "setting this os. I want to use this os variable in main class"

def run():
  # Some code ..........
  process = Process(target=executor, args=(...))  # executer method gets call from here


  # Some code ..........
  # want to use 'test_count' here somewhere
```

in executor method I am setting one os variable. I want to use that variable in main class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot change the environment of a parent process. Either return the value and deal with it in the main process or use some of the [shareable structures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to exchange values between your processes.

Comment: I am not changing the environment of parent process. I am setting os variable for the first time in child process. and I want to use that variable in parent process.

Comment: Is it possible to set some global variable??

Comment: Implemented with shareable structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process shared [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) from *multiprocessing* module. The code may look something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def executor(queue):
    queue.put({"key": "value"})

def run(queue):
    process = Process(target=executor, args=(queue,))
    process.start()
    process.join()
    print(queue.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(Queue())
```

Output:

```
>>> {'key': 'value'}
```

There are also [proxy objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) for sharing data between multiple processes.